# Is there a better way to read elements from a Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to read data from an NSDictionary in Swift, which is a parameter in a delegate method I"m implementing (specifically, the `advertisementData` parameter):

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: NSDictionary!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {}
```

I've played with several different incarnations, but the only way I've figured out to pull data elements from this dictionary seems overly complicated.

For example, to pull a String from the dictionary, I had to do this:

```
let localNamePre: AnyObject? = advertisementData.objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
if let localName = localNamePre as? String {
   // do stuff
}
```

Or for an Array:

```
let serviceDictPre: AnyObject? = advertisementData.objectForKey(CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey)
if let serviceDict = serviceDictPre as? Array<CBUUID> {
   // do stuff            
}
```

This just seems like an overly complicated way to convert to the final datatype.  Is there a better way to do this that perhaps skips the `AnyObject` intermediate variable?  Everything else I've attempted has resulted in a crash because I'm trying to unwrap a nil value.

Comment: There are useful answers here; just note that Cocoa is slowly getting a Swift makeover. Some frameworks are currently easier to access than others, but you should expect it to improve over time so that there are far fewer `AnyObject` and `!` required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there's a way, add an extension method to `NSDictionary` like this:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func extractObjectForKey<T>(key: String, type: T.Type) -> T? {
        let value: AnyObject? = self.objectForKey(key)
        return value as? T
    }
}
```

and use as follows (tested in a playground):

```
var dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict["int"] = 5
dict["string"] = "Hello"

dict.extractObjectForKey("int", type:Int.self) // Prints {Some 5}
dict.extractObjectForKey("string", type: String.self) // Prints {Some "Hello"}
dict.extractObjectForKey("int", type:String.self) // Prints nil (it's not a string)
```

Comment: Hmm, I like this idea, but it's not working for me.  I've implemented this exact code in a playground, but I'm getting "nil" for each of the `extractObjectForKey` calls.  Ideas?

Comment: Very odd... tried right now with beta 7 and it still works. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using beta 7 as well.  Here is a screenshot of my playground.  I copied/pasted your code without any changes: [Xcode Screenshot](http://imagebin.org/319124)

Comment: Tried right now and my output hasn't changed :S. Try renaming the extension func to something else (`test_extractObjectForKey` would be fine), just to be sure its name doesn't collide

Comment: Same output when renaming to `test_extractObjectForKey`.  Something strange is going on.  Thanks for the original suggestion.  I'll keep playing around to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Can you try (if you haven't yet) on a new playground file, and if that doesn't work, in a project?

Comment: I just tried a new playground file, same result.  I also have tried from within the project and I get the same result as well.  In fact, getting nils within the project is what led me to try it in a playground in the first place.

Comment: I'm clueless... tried ios and macos, beta 7 and 6, and it works in all cases, with the same output. checked your code line by line and it is actually the same.

Comment: Well I feel sheepish. The release notes brought me to the beta 7 page, so I thought I was at the latest, but I was actually just running beta1!  Updating to the latest fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement an utility function that returns an object with the specific properties you need?
example declare a class:

```
class MyAdData{
 var localName : String = ""
 var serviceDict : Array = []

}
```

Utility Function:

```
func getAdData(advertisementData: NSDictionary!)->myAdData{
//instantiate myAdData : MyAdData
//Do your extraction (let ... Blah Blah) and populate in myAdData
//return myAddData : MyAdData


}
```